# Understanding of persp plot

Tags: r, data-visualization

I do not understand the persp plot, my example is:

```
c<-mat.or.vec(5,2)
c[1,1]<-1
c[1,2]<-1
c[2,1]<-1
c[2,2]<-1
c[3,1]<-2
c[3,2]<-0
c[4,1]<-1
c[4,2]<-1
c[5,1]<-1
c[5,2]<-1

persp(c,xlab = "X", theta = -60,ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z",ticktype = "detailed"
)
```

I get the following graphic:

[image: plot of persp understanding]

But I do not understand it?!

I mean, why are the x and y axis from 0 to 1? What values does the plot take? I thougt it takes the column and row values from the matrix, so like [5,] gives 5 e.g.. Or how does this plot generates?

The matrix is

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    2    0
[4,]    1    1
[5,]    1    1
```

And I thought the first point is like x=1, y= 1 and z =1 and so on? Or x=3 and y=1 z=2?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with how you created your matrix, but I am not expert enough in R to figure out what it is. Maybe someone else will. 

I added the R tag to help find them

Answer (score 5):

The function does exactly, what it is supposed to do. First of all, you did not specify any x or y values, but only a matrix of z values. Thus the function creates x and y automatically.  This is done by transforming the row numbers of the matrix into an equally spaced sequence from 0 to 1 and the same for column numbers and y values. Please read the help page of the function for more information.

See what happens if we append another column:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,2,1,1,1,1,0,1,1),ncol=2)
mat <- cbind(mat,c(1,1,1,1,1))

persp(mat,xlab = "X", theta = -60,ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z",ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image: perspective plot]

And here is the way to specify x and y:

```
persp(x=1:5,y=1:3,z=mat,xlab = "X", theta = -60,ylab = "Y", zlab = "Z",ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image]

PS: Don't call an R object `c`, because that's the name of a heavily used function.